# Spring Integration Java DSL bridge to poll two different directories

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-dsl

I have setup file poller/channel adapter which polls a directory and handler integration flow using Java DSL. But I am not getting any reference how to add another directory/channel adapter and bridge to same handler. Here is my code.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(incomingDir)).
                    filter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv")).
                    filter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>()),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(500).maxMessagesPerPoll(1))).
            handle(fileMessageToJobRequest()).
            handle(jobLaunchingGateway).
            log(LoggingHandler.Level.WARN, "headers.id + ': ' + payload").
            get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first class citizens in Spring Integration is a `MessageChannel` entity. You always can set explicit channels between endpoints in you `IntegrationFlow` definition and explicitly send messages to them.

For you “merging” use-case I would suggest to place a `.channel()` before `.handle()` and declare the second flow for the second directory, but in the end of that flow use the same `.channel()` to “bridge” messages from this flow to the middle of the first one.

See more information in the reference manual : https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-channels

Comment: Thanks @Artem. Will that result into following ?

Comment: Right, that's correct. Exactly what I suggested for you. Is it clear now how it works?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Artem. How about following ?

```
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlowUi(JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(incomingDirUi)).
                    filter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv")).
                    filter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>()),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(500).maxMessagesPerPoll(1))).
            channel("to-bridge").
            handle(fileMessageToJobRequest()).
            handle(jobLaunchingGateway).
            log(LoggingHandler.Level.WARN, "headers.id + ': ' + payload").
            get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlowSftp(JobLaunchingGateway jobLaunchingGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(incomingDirSftp)).
                    filter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv")).
                    filter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>()),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(500).maxMessagesPerPoll(1))).
            channel("to-bridge").get();
}
```